# How to remove specific objects from strong parameters if a certain value is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5 app.
I am sending an array of attendances_attributes from my Angular 7 app. These are coming from a grid of form fields where I let the user add a bulk of time reports for a complete month. I let them send empty time report fields too but I only want to save the time reports that are filled in. How can I remove reports where the starts_at_time is not set from the strong parameters before saving to the database?

**This is my code:**

```
def report_params
    params.permit(:title, :description, attendances_attributes: [:id, :timetype_id, :starts_at_date, :starts_at_time, :ends_at_date, :ends_at_time, :description, :hours, :minutes, :_destroy])
  end
```

In other words I want to check the reports_params for attendances_attributes where the starts_at_time is null and remove that object from the array/parameters and then save it to the database. How can I do this?

**I tried this and it did nothing**

```
def update
        report_params['attendances_attributes'].each_with_index  do |report, index|
            unless report['starts_at_time']
                report_params['attendances_attributes'].delete_at(index)
            end
        end
        @report = Report.find params[:id]
        if @report.update_attributes report_params
            render "api/v1/reports/show"
        else
            respond_with @report
        end
    end
```

**Update**

These are my controller parameters

```
def report_params
  params.permit(:title, :description, attendances_attributes: [:id, :timetype_id, :starts_at_date, :starts_at_time, :ends_at_date, :ends_at_time, :description, :hours, :minutes, :_destroy])
end
```

The input from Angular is:

```
{
    "title" => "Report august", "description" => "", "attendances_attributes" => [{
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-01",
        "starts_at_time" => "12:00",
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-01",
        "ends_at_time" => "14:00",
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-02",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-02",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-03",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-03",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-04",
        "starts_at_time" => "08:00",
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-04",
        "ends_at_time" => "10:00",
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-05",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-05",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-06",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-06",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-07",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-07",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-08",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-08",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-09",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-09",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-10",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-10",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-11",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-11",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-12",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-12",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-13",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-13",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-14",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-14",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-15",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-15",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-16",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-16",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-17",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-17",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-18",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-18",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-19",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-19",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-20",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-20",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-21",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-21",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-22",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-22",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-23",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-23",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-24",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-24",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-25",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-25",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-26",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-26",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-27",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-27",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-28",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-28",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-29",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-29",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-30",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-30",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }, {
        "id" => nil,
        "otype" => nil,
        "user_id" => nil,
        "timetype_id" => nil,
        "starts_at_date" => "2019-08-31",
        "starts_at_time" => nil,
        "ends_at_date" => "2019-08-31",
        "ends_at_time" => nil,
        "hours" => nil,
        "minutes" => nil,
        "description" => nil,
        "break" => nil,
        "_destroy" => ""
    }]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
new_report_params = report_params.dig(:attendances_attributes).reject do |attendances_attribute|
  attendances_attribute.dig(:starts_at_time).nil?
end

if @report.update_attributes new_report_params
    render "api/v1/reports/show"
else
    respond_with @report
end
```

Comment: I tried your solution but got the error: TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

Comment: Can you share the params on the controller?

Comment: I have added it to my question now.

Comment: I wanted to see the params with values after posted the form.

Comment: try this: if report_params[:attendances_attributes]['0'][:starts_at_time].blank? instead of if report_params.dig(:attendances_attributes, :starts_at_time).nil?

Comment: Same error unfortunately. I have added my input params now.

Comment: try  if report_params[:attendances_attributes].first[:starts_at_time].blank?

Comment: Well technically there is no more errors, BUT it does not find the 30 days in the  report_params[:attendances_attributes] that got no starts_at_time (only 1 day got it and should be created, the other 30 should be removed/ignored).

Comment: Well, I get no errors and attendances_attribute.dig(:starts_at_time).nil? returns false for the two days I got starts_at_time on and true for the ones that are nil. So that part works too, but 31 days/records are still being created instead of just 2. Could it be that the changes I make to the params are not saved/used?

Comment: There are 31 records. 2 records removed because its starts_at_time value nil. So that part works? Then,  29 records need to be saved but it saves 31 records?

Comment: The other way around. Two days got starts_at_time (and should be saved) and 29 are lacking the starts_at_time and should not be saved. But all 31 days are saved unfortunately so it looks like the changes we are doing to the params is ignored when saving. Perhaps it is not really rejecting these records/days from the params or it is not saved.

Comment: I think the problem will be understood if you do debug with **pry** before updating.